# Using .col-* in .d-flex container bootstrap 4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

Is it (allowed) recommended to use `.col-*`'s as children in a `.d-flex` container? Or is it not the way `.d-flex` should be used but rather use `.row`?

---

In the [Bootstrap 4 Docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/) I cant find any example which uses a `.col-*` in a `.d-flex` container. They are only using layouts like this

```
<div class="d-flex flex-row">
  <div class="p-2">Flex item 1</div>
  <div class="p-2">Flex item 2</div>
  <div class="p-2">Flex item 3</div>
</div>
<div class="d-flex flex-row-reverse">
  <div class="p-2">Flex item 1</div>
  <div class="p-2">Flex item 2</div>
  <div class="p-2">Flex item 3</div>
</div>
```

But these `.p-2` classes doens't make these cols responsive. They only have a `padding` defined and no `width` has been given.

**So for example I want something like this:**

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="d-flex flex-wrap">
  <div class="col-sm-3 col-12">
    Responsive cols
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3 col-12">
    Responsive cols
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3 col-12">
    Responsive cols
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3 col-12">
    Responsive cols
  </div>
</div>
```

Is a good or bad practice according Bootstrap? I can't find anything related about `.d-flex` and `.col-*` combined.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As explained the docs...

> "Rows are wrappers for columns. Each column has horizontal padding
>   (called a gutter) for controlling the space between them. This padding
>   is then counteracted on the rows with negative margins. This way, all
>   the content in your columns is visually aligned down the left side."

Therefore, `col-*` are supposed to be the immediate children `.row`. Also `.row` and `col-*` are designed together as a grid. This allows [columns to wrap](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#column-wrapping) to the next line as needed. The wrapping works in your example because of `flex-wrap`.

So, 2 reasons `col-*` should be in `row` instead of `d-flex`:

- left/right side alignment with container content
- column wrapping according to grid widths

Compare `col-*` inside `row` vs `d-flex`: https://www.codeply.com/go/82ecXXvpkO

Comment: If using the grid use `.row`. If I want extra responsiveness in components where I dont use the grid I can use `.d-flex` and `.flex-wrap`. Its clear to me now where both should be used. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

> I can't find any example which uses a `.col-*` in a `.d-flex`
>   container.

This should be your first indication that yes, you ought to rely on `.row`.  The `d-flex` class applies the following CSS:

```
.d-flex {
  display: -webkit-box!important;
  display: -ms-flexbox!important;
  display: flex!important;
}
```

And *that's it*.  Meanwhile `.row` interacts with `.container` (or `.container-fluid)`.  It also provides additional margin settings so that your nested `.col-*-*` items are positioned correctly.

The `d-flex` class is part of Bootstrap 4s "Utility" classes; these are classes designed to provide you additional flexibility with your layout and structure; not to replace more robust components like Grid.

Comment: Yes I understand not to replace `.d-flex` with `.row`. But what if I dont want to use the `.row` class in certain circumstances? I can use `.col-*` and `.d-flex`?

Comment: @Red - The columns will still obey their breakpoint declarations, but as I mentioned above you will lose all of the margin and positioning provided by the container and row classes.  Given that `.row` is *already* flex I'm struggling to see any reason to avoid using it.  Also, `col-xs-*` does not exist in Bootstrap 4.